# Python constrained non-linear optimization with scipy.optimize fails to find optimal solutions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a problem I am trying to find a solution for where I have 5 single variable polynomials that have a single peak in the range i'm concerned with. My goal is to find some values of the variable for each polynomial (under certain min/max and sum of all variables constraints) that maximizes the value of these curves multiplied by a constant for each curve.

I've set up some code using the scipy.optimize package and numpy. It seems to be able to reach solution, but the solution it reaches does not appear to be anywhere close to optimal. For example, the trivial case is for an input of 488 MW. This particular input value has a solution where each x0-x4 variable is it at the peak of it's function, which is as follows:

```
x0=90
x1=100
x2=93
x3=93
x4=112

The result it provides we with is:

x0=80
x1=97
x2=105
x3=80
x4=126

This does satisfy my constraint, but it does not appear to minimize the objective function. 

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import minimize



U1_Max=103
U1_Min=80
U2_Max=102
U2_Min=80
U3_Max=105
U3_Min=80
U4_Max=100
U4_Min=80
U5_Max=126
U5_Min=90


# Our whole goal here is to maximze the sum of several efficiency efficiency curves times the
# output MW of each unit. "The most efficiency where it matters the most"
# Assuming all units are available for assignment his would look something like:

#Where have the following efficiency curves:
#U1: Efficiency=-0.0231*(MW)^2+4.189*MW-102.39
#U2: Efficiency= -0.01*(MW)^2+1.978*MW-8.7451
#U3: Efficiency= -0.025*MW^2+4.5017*MW-115.37
#U4: Efficiency= -0.01*(MW)^2+1.978*MW-8.7451
#U5: Efficiency= -0.0005*(MW)^2+0.1395*(MW)^2-13.327*MW+503.41

#So I think we want to
#Maximize U1(x0)*U1_MAX+U2(x1)*U2_MAX+U3(x2)*U3_MAX+U4(x3)*U4_MAX+U5(x4)*U5_MAX
#I think this can also be stated as:
#Minimize (U1(x0)-100)*U1_MAX+(U2(x1)-100)*U2_MAX)+(U3(x2)-100)*U3_MAX)+(U4(x3)-100)*U4_MAX)+(U5(x4)-100)*U5_MAX)
#Which means 'minimize the sum of the products of the difference between 100% efficient and actual and the unit nameplates'

#By Choosing {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}

#Such that x1+x2+x3+x4+x5=MW_Total
#Such that U1_Min<x1<U1Max
#Such that U2_Min<x2<U2Max
#Such that U3_Min<x3<U3Max
#Such that U4_Min<x4<U4Max
#Such that U5_Min<x5<U5Max

##so let's type that out....
#stack overflow says the optimizer does best if the function being optimized is around 1-5ish so we will get it there-ish. 
def objective(x):
  return (
      (
      ((100-0.0231*x[0]**2+4.189*x[0]-102.39))*U1_Max
      +((100-0.01*x[1]**2+1.978*x[1]-8.7451))*U2_Max
      +((100-0.025*x[2]**2+4.5017*x[2]-115.37))*U3_Max
      +((100-0.01*x[3]**2+1.978*x[3]-8.7451))*U4_Max
      +((100-0.0005*x[4]**3+0.1395*x[4]**2-13.327*x[4]+503.41))*U5_Max
      )

      )

x=np.zeros(5)

print(
      (
      ((100-0.0231*x[0]**2+4.189*x[0]-102.39))*U1_Max
      +((100-0.01*x[1]**2+1.978*x[1]-8.7451))*U2_Max
      +((100-0.025*x[2]**2+4.5017*x[2]-115.37))*U3_Max
      +((100-0.01*x[3]**2+1.978*x[3]-8.7451))*U4_Max
      +((100-0.0005*x[4]**3+0.1395*x[4]**2-13.327*x[4]+503.41))*U5_Max
      )

      )

#Now, let's formally define our constraints
#Note that this must be of a form that satisfies 'constraint equal to zero'
#First, the sum of all MW commands should be qual to the total MW commanded
def constraint1(x):
    return -x[0]-x[1]-x[2]-x[3]-x[4]+MW_Total

#Since this is a numeric process let's give it some starting 'guess' conditions.
n=5
x0=np.zeros(n)
x0[0]=90
x0[1]=100
x0[2]=93
x0[3]=93
x0[4]=112

# show initial starting uess
print('Start by guessing: ')
print(x0)
print('Which gives a scaled algorithim value of: ')
print(
      (
      ((100-0.0231*x0[0]**2+4.189*x0[0]-102.39))*U1_Max
      +((100-0.01*x0[1]**2+1.978*x0[1]-8.7451))*U2_Max
      +((100-0.025*x0[2]**2+4.5017*x0[2]-115.37))*U3_Max
      +((100-0.01*x0[3]**2+1.978*x0[3]-8.7451))*U4_Max
      +((100-0.0005*x0[4]**3+0.1395*x0[4]**2-13.327*x0[4]+503.41))*U5_Max
      )

      )
print('Which gives actual MW total of: ')
print(x0[0]+x0[1]+x0[2]+x0[3]+x0[4])


#Next, Let's give it some bounds to operate in
U1_Bnds=(U1_Min, U1_Max)
U2_Bnds=(U2_Min, U2_Max)
U3_Bnds=(U3_Min, U3_Max)
U4_Bnds=(U4_Min, U4_Max)
U5_Bnds=(U5_Min, U5_Max)
Bnds=(U1_Bnds, U2_Bnds, U3_Bnds, U4_Bnds, U5_Bnds)

con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}
print('MW Generated is: ')
for i in range (410,536):
  MW_Total=i
  solution = minimize(objective,x0,method='SLSQP',bounds=Bnds,constraints=con1,options={'maxiter': 10000000, 'eps':1.4901161193847656e-10})
  x = solution.x
  print(solution.x[0],solution.x[1],solution.x[2],solution.x[3],solution.x[4])
```

I would expect that for my trivial case of 488 MW it would give me the optimal answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your objective and constraint definition, it looks like you are in the case of a quadratic objective function with a linear constraint.

The theory for this is well known and provides convergence guarantees, you can refer to [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Equality_constraints).

I don't know that well the scipy SLSQP interface but it looks like you are using less information than what you could do. Try to cast your problem in the form of Quadratic objective function with linear constraint. Also cast your constraint in a `scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint` object.

And please use functions calls such as `print(objective(x))` and `print(solution.x)` in your code, this would enhance readability.